# Spring Batch - Staging table design - transfer data to main table

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am developing a data loader application which uses flat file to read data and insert in to temporary staging table.This is done using MultiResourcePartitioner(**thread pool 10-11,queue 151**) , where each step runs parallel for each file. There are around **15000** files , so once first **set of 150 file resources** is completed, **jobexecutiondecider** will **again run another 150 files** similarly, this way till 15000 files are completed.

Next step is to move data from staging table to main table and after this ,files will be compressed and moved to another location . I require your inputs ,on designing staging and archiving step,to have moderate throughput,if the job fails,during the next run ,i.e. after some 3 hours, it should clean all the stale data and move **COMPLETED** data to  main table .when i say **COMPLETED**,it means a full complete file is read successfully and inserted to the staging table. Only these data are moved to the main table.we also have another table that stores file name ,filepath and completion status and updated on succesful file completion , updated afterStep method.

**Note:**

we do not want to directly insert in to the main table, because the table has materialized view, so removing stale data in the main table will affect business users viewing report, one time they see records, next time the records are vanished because of job running hourly and cleans unsuccessful data.

my current approach is to run staging step   parallel to the multiresourcepartitioner step , and have a scheduled task executor with fixed delay of 2 mins , the tasklet bean polls staging table , move the data which has processed flag Y and delete from staged table, also monitor the partitioner step , whether it is running or stopped. if it is running tasklet will return RepeatStatus.CONTINUE, if the partitioner step is completed ,then  RepeatStatus.FINISHED is done . Last step will archive the files.when the job starts again 
, if some archive file is not completed , which is known from another table that stores file name etc with column is_archived is Y not archived , A archived.let me know your comments.

Comment: I think, your question is not about `spring-batch` specifically (I hope it does it job good) but about SQL import strategies in general (which I hope I've covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976294/spring-batch-partition-step-to-rollback-all-the-previous-chunk-commit-s-when/7982547#7982547)). Perhaps you can be more specific about your question (describe your issues / limitations / improvement points)?

Comment: my question was,is the approach mentioned in 3rd paragraph is better do u have any other approach .

Comment: You can try different approaches and try what works for you better. If you ask here, perhaps you face some problems. Tell us, what they are and community may come with a solution then.